# How to extract sub-vectors of different datatypes from vector<char>?

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, open3d

I have a `std::vector<char> data` which represents data from a network byte-stream as well as different offsets as integer values. I know that the vector holds the data for a 4x4 trajectory matrix (32bit float), a RGB image ([Unity TextureFormat.RGB24](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.RGB24.html)) and a gray scale image ([Unity TextureFormat.RFloat](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.RFloat.html)).

What I need to do is the extract the following from this data:

- `Eigen::Matrix4d trajectory`
- `std::vector<uint8_t> rgb_image_data`
- `std::vector<uint8_t> gray_image_data`

I want to do TSDF Volume integration with RGBD images using [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/cpp_api/index.html).
I have the same setup as python script already working (simply using numpy arrays for the data buffers), but need to rewrite it in `C++` and I'm quite unsure how to do these conversions best.

Comment: You can get the raw bytes by `my_vector.data()`. Given an offset, you can get the buffer at a certain position as `std::next(my_vector.data(), offset)`. Then it's all `reinterpret_cast<Eigen::Matrix4d*>(...)`. Note that the data should be properly aligned for the types you intend to extract, otherwise you risk undefined behaviour.

Comment: It looks like a serialize/deserialize problem, which it can be tricky, especially if you get the serialized data from a different machine (small and big edian differences). How the std::vector<char> data has been created? Usually, serialize and deserialize goes in pair. If you wrote the code that produce the vector then it is easier (potentially).

Comment: @lubgr thanks, I'll test this out. data should be correctly aligned, so this shouldn't be a problem (hopefully^^).

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi The other side is a Unity application, where I manually create the data stream from the images (block copy of the results of [GetRawTextureData()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetRawTextureData.html) into a single byte array, that is sent over LAN), so this should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the bytes into objects of the right type

```
std::vector<char> data = /* get from network */;
Eigen::Matrix4d trajectory;
std::vector<uint8_t> rgb_image_data(rgb_image_size);
std::vector<uint8_t> gray_image_data(gray_image_size);

std::memcpy(&trajectory, data.data() + trajectory_offset, sizeof(Eigen::Matrix4d));
std::memcpy(rgb_image_data.data(), data.data() + rgb_image_offset, rgb_image_size);
std::memcpy(gray_image_data.data(), data.data() + gray_image_offset, gray_image_size);
```

That is assuming that the source copied in a whole `Eigen::Matrix4d`, rather than the `double[4][4]` it contains.

Comment: This assumes that `Eigen::Matrix4d` is trivially copyable, right? I guess that's fair to assume, but you might want to put a `static_assert` somewhere.

Comment: @lubgr well, so does the `reinterpret_cast`, but my understanding of Eigen is that the fixed size dense matrixes are basically `template <typename T, size_t N> class Matrix { T data[N][N]; public: /*methods*/ };`

Comment: I'm wondering: why do I have to copy the data and not simply point to the data in the original vector? The original `std::vector<char> data` should already be a copy of the network stream as far as I'm aware: it is the filled buffer from winsocks `recv()` function, which I given as argument to the function that contains the code above. Or can I pass the network buffer by reference and then do the memcopy operations as shown above?

Comment: Ok that's good to know I wasn't sure whether the `reinterpret_cast` does require trivial copyability when you work with pointers.

Comment: @RolandDeschain because you specified objects that own their data. You can have a `std::span<uint8_t>` that points into `data`, similarly an `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix4d>`. Copying also side-steps possible alignment issues. Yes, you could `recv` into these instead of copying into a `std::vector<char>`

Comment: OK, thank you. So I will pass the original vector by reference, do the memcopy as shown here. As soon as I get it to work, I'll mark the answer. Thanks again for the helpful comments and answers! :)